# Referencing to pairs of values in a array list and then comparing them

Tags: java, arraylist, comparison

So I have an array list, within a file, with word pairs, one in English and one in Danish. I then pass one of the words into a GUI I have made and then the user writes what they think it is in the other language.

The problem I am facing is that I can't just say that Question needs to equal answer, as they are 2 different languages, and I am not sure how to go about this.

Would a kind soul please help me out with this? :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhrDs.jpg Here's a picture of the GUI if you need some help understanding what I'm talking about.

```
public class Quizz
{
    static void add(Quizz quizzlist)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public String getQuestion()
    {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question)
    {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getAnswer()
    {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer)
    {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    private String question;
    private String answer;

    public Quizz(String question, String answer)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    public String toFile()
    {
        return answer + "," + question;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you already have `paired` word, it will surely in thinking that the question is `equal` to the answer!

Comment: I'm not sure how to compare them though is the problem. Because if I just compare the two words straight in the code it will just be something like is a = b? No. a = a, if you get what I mean. I am not sure how to do this personally within the array list.

Comment: I think you can use `HashMap`, which is most suitable for your requirement! which is originally a `paired` array list as you can understand!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem well, you would like to map an English word to its equivalent in Danish (and the other way around as well)... and to be able to:

- check if the user's answer matches the "Danish" side of the map when the
  "question" was an English word AND
- check if the user's answer matches the "English" side of the map when the "question" was a Danish word.

Basically, what you want is a bi-directional Map. Google's Guava [BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) might be what you're looking for. Here is an example of how you can use it:

```
import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;

public class BiMapTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final BiMap<String, String> biMap = HashBiMap.create();

        biMap.put("english_word", "danish_equivalent");

        System.out.println("english_word's Danish equivalent is: " + biMap.get("english_word"));
        System.out.println("danish_equivalent's English original word is: " + biMap.inverse().get("danish_equivalent"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your array list structure, is there one array list or two?

And do you mean the Question is "Apple" then the answer should be "æble"?

Posting more codes may help peoples know what you want.

---

To compare strings, use equals(String str) method instead of simply using "=" sign.

```
public boolean checkAnswer(String answer){
    return (this.answer.equals(answer));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I can post moer code, I was just unsure what part of the code people would be needing. 

Basically I have a array list that holds the word pairs, which I will edit into the OP in a second.

And yes, that is basically what the GUI would be doing.

Comment: I've added the entire class where the Quizz list is in.

Comment: @MadsRosenmeyer It seems that only one Question and one Answer in your Quizz class, what you may want to do may be add compare method that return a bool value to indicate right or wrong. I have updated my post, see whether it's what you want.